# What is the pattern for executing multiple Cucumber tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to construct a suite of Cucumber tests using Selenium. The first step in each test logs in to a web application.

I'm using the Selenium ChromeDriver, and I can see that Cucumber is using dependency injection to initialise the driver. After each test completes I would like to start fresh with a new web browser, but Cucumber insists on using the same driver used in the previous test. I've tried a number of things to start from a clean point. I'm not sure what the recommended way of doing this is, I presume you have to use the 'Hooks' class, as that contains methods which run before and after each test scenario. Here's what I currently have:

```
public class Hooks {

    private final WebDriver driver;

    @Inject
    public Hooks(final WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @Before
    public void openWebSite() {
    }

    @After
    public void closeSession() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I put a `driver.close()` statement into the `@After` method, but I don't see a method to reopen, or recreate a new session, and I'm getting the following exception when the next test tries to log in:

```
Message: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
```

Presumably because it didn't like the fact that I just called `close()`.

But really, I want to tell Cucumber that I'd like a completely fresh driver to be used for each test scenario.

I've searched around for Cucumber examples, but all the example code I've found just involves one single test. I didn't turn up anything which was using a suite of tests, aiming to do something similar to what I've described above.

What's the recommended pattern for this?

Comment: Not a lot of experience in spring... Instead of injecting the driver why not call the driver initialization method directly in the Before hook.

Comment: Which dependency injection framework are you using?

Comment: @Marit - looks like it's using the javax.inject package for the Inject annotation

Comment: not sure that's supported by cucumber. afaik you can only use Before and After hooks. you might want to try one of the dependency frameworks supported by Cucumber. That can manage creation/destruction of the webDriver per scenario for you